# A question from the Chinese National Entrance Exam

Tags: polynomials

> If the function $f(x)=2x^3-ax^2+1\; :a\in\mathbb{R}\;$ has one and only one zero value in the interval $(0,\infty)$, then what what is the sum of the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ in the interval $[-1,1]$?

This is an "intermediate" level question I looked at the Chinese university entrance exam for fun. I tried to work through this problem but wasn't able to come to an answer. Seems like an interesting question that some people would like to give a try.

Comment: You might want to take a look at how to appropriately use Mathjax.

Comment: There are two ways a polynomial of the third degree (with a positive third degree coefficient) can go: either from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ with at most some hesitation, or it goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ with a summit and a valley. Is it possible for that particular polynomial not to have a summit and a valley? What does that say about the zero point? ... => once you've figured that one out, you'll understand how to proceed.

Comment: Some first steps. If there is only one zero on that interval, then the derivative is also zero at that point. The derivative is $f'(x)=6x^2 -2ax=2(3x-a)$, so we must have $a$ so that $f(a/3) = 0 \Rightarrow 2(a/3)^3 - a \cdot (a/3)^2 +1 = -\frac{1}{27}a^3 +1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I only saw after writing this that a similar reasoning was posted by user @Matti P. in comments. I guess you can consider it as more of a reasoning behind his comment.

$f(x)$ has one root in $(0,\infty)$. First consider $f'(x)=6x^2-2ax=2x(3x-a)$.

Case 1: $a>0$. This means $f(x)$ decreases in $(0,a/3)$. Since $f(0)=1$, it follows that between $0,a/3$ the only root would occur at $a/3$. If it occurs at some $x<a/3$, it will occur again. This gives $f(a/3)=0$ and $a=3$.

Case 2: $a<0$. Now $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0, \infty)$. And $f(0)=1$. So, no root can be present in this interval.

$a=0$ clearly doesn't satisfy our condition.

So, $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2+1$. As already noted, $f(x)$ is increasing in $(-\infty, 0)$ therefore in the interval $[-1,0]$ the maximum is attained at $f(0)=1$ and minimumn at $f(-1)=-4$. In the interval $[0,1]$ the maximum is attained at $f(0)=1$ and minimum at $f(1)=0$. Combining these two, $\max_{x \in [-1,1]} f(x) = f(0)$ and $\min_{x \in [-1,1]} f(x) =f(-1)$.